# How to resolve <main id="main" class=""> error on google console?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

Can anyone help me how to solve error of `<main id="main" class="">` on google page speed.

Here is screenshot for the errors.

Website link is https://www.kritarthhandicrafts.com/

[image: screen shot of error]

Comment: Question not clear and where is the error? tell us details

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```html
<main id="main">
```

Because you're not using any classes, there's no need to set the `class` attribute, and thus you should remove it.